# How to fire event onkeydown after entering at least 3 characters?

Tags: javascript, events, onkeydown

how to fire event onkeydown after entering at least 3 characters?
i will enter they in autocomplete, and after 3 characters calling function `"autoload()"` .

```
 <input type="text" id="autocomplete" onkeydown="autoLoad();" />
```

maybe I need some other event?

Comment: A basic if statement inside autoLoad. `if (the Length < 3) return`

Comment: can you show me please? i have no Idea at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just bind the keydown Event like you did then inside the function (autoLoad()) you check if the field has more then 3 chars, if it does then continue the script.

EDIT:
I think this should work

```
function autoLoad() {
    if (document.getElementById('autocomplete').value.length >= 3) {
        // it has more then 3 chars
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is, that iam inside a function after typing one character and not going further to second. maybe Event onkeydown is not a good one. what you think?

Comment: Everytime you do the 'onkeydown()' event the function is called, I mostly use the onkeyup, cause onkeydown does not register the 'new' char(s)

Answer (score -1):

Pass the element into the autoLoad function ans check the length before your executable code.

```
... onkeydown="autoLoad(this)" ...


autoLoad = function ( element ){
    if(element.value.length > 3){
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Chs3L/

Comment: There is no `val()` method on a DOM object

Comment: Good call. Corercted for this content.